# input para dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, lista, for

aprendi muito com as respostas de vocês. Mas eu to com um problema aqui. Eu não estou conseguindo entrar com valores para dentro de uma lista vazia. Meu exercício é este:
Faça um programa que o usuário irá digitar 10 números e você irá mostrar:

- Qual foi o menor valor
- Qual foi o maior valor
- Qual a média dos valores

Eu fiz isso aqui:
lista = []
passo = range(1,10+1)
for i in passo:
  lista = lista.append(input('Digite o {}º número: '.format(i)))
  print(lista)
Quando eu printo a lista a lista esta com o ultimo valor digitato. Ou seja não foi sequenciada.
Eu queria encontrar um jeito de jogar as variáveis imputadas pelo usuário dentro de uma lista, e depois só usar min(), max(), sum()/i para resolver. Mas não consegui fazer com que os inputs fosse para dentro de uma lista.

Answer (score -2):

Bom então, se eu entendi bem o seu código só não está rodando por conta do trecho:

> lista = lista.append(input('Digite o {}º número: '.format(i)))

, onde o `lista =` está tentando atribuir um valor vazio (NoneType) ao array antes do valor inserido pelo usuário ser registrado já no começo. Removendo esse trecho , o primeiro valor inserido ao array será o do input. Outro detalhe é que a função input do python retorna uma string, mesmo se for digitado um valor (isso pode ocasionar em um TypeError durante a divisão para obter a média) então para o cálculo você pode converter para int ou float adicionando a função int() ou float() no input da seguinte forma :

```
lista = [] 
passo = range(1,10+1)
for i in passo: 
  lista.append(int(input('Digite o {}º número: '.format(i))))   
print(max(lista))
print(min(lista))
print(sum(lista)/i)
```